# How to pass `noconstant` or other options from wrapper program to inside `regress` call

Tags: stata

I would like to pass the `noconstant` option from a wrapper program to an inside `regress` call. The following solution works, but it seems particularly janky and not extensible if I would like to pass several options.

```
webuse grunfeld, clear

capture program drop regress_wrapper
program define regress_wrapper
    version 11.2
    syntax varlist(min=2 numeric) [if] [in] ///
        [, noconstant(string)]
    tokenize `varlist'
    local y `1'
    macro shift
    local x `*'
    regress `y' `x', `noconstant'
end    

regress_wrapper invest mvalue kstock
regress_wrapper invest mvalue kstock, noconstant(noconstant)
```

I thought that something more like the following would work, but it doesn't pass the `noconstant` option.

```
capture program drop regress_wrapper
program define regress_wrapper
    version 11.2
    syntax varlist(min=2 numeric) [if] [in] ///
        [, noconstant]
    tokenize `varlist'
    local y `1'
    macro shift
    local x `*'
    regress `y' `x', `noconstant'
end    

regress_wrapper invest mvalue kstock
regress_wrapper invest mvalue kstock, noconstant
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second doesn't work because the local macro ends up being called `constant`, not `noconstant`, as described at [`help syntax##optionally_off`](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?syntax#optionally_off). So it should work if you replace:

```
   regress `y' `x', `noconstant'
```

by:

```
   regress `y' `x', `constant'
```

If you want to pass several options on, it's easier to use the `*` syntax explained at [`help syntax##description_of_options`](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?syntax#description_of_options) :

> If you also specify
>       *, any remaining options are collected and placed, one after the other in
>       `options'.

e.g.:

```
       syntax varlist(min=2 numeric) [if] [in] ///
            [, *]
       ...
       regress `y' `x', `options'
```